# dart: Instance variable of type String with only certain values

Tags: dart, types, instance-variables

is there a way in dart to define an instance variable of type String to only hold certain values.
For example in TypeScript one can achieve this as follows:

```
class Test {
   name: string;
   type: 'Unit' | 'Integration';
}
```

I've already considered defining an enum, however as far as I'm concerned you can't provide enums with custom values in dart.

Comment: "however as far as I'm concerned you can't provide enums with custom values in dart." but you want to restrict the possible values? Or do you mean you want something where you can have whatever value but certain places you want to make sure the value can only be `Unit` and `Integration`?

Comment: I want to restrict the possible values.
Such that type can only be _Unit_ or _Integration_ at all times.

Comment: Well, the solution would be to use an enum since Dart does not have a way to indicate certain specific values is valid. Having custom data attached to your enum is not possible right now but work is being done right now to add that feature to Dart (it is implemented right now and seems to be ready for Dart 2.17).

Comment: Alright, thank you!